# frame crash when open two mainloop

Tags: wxpython

i try to do a chat with rooms.The user login and then choose room.After that,the chat open.In the chat,the user can go to another room.
I in level of gui now.When the main gui(the chat) up,the user can write what he want.The problem is when he choose to go another room(that in this option,open another gui of choose room)the gui crash- "python.exe has stopped working".
my question is if it possible to run app with app.mainloop and run after a few minutes another app.mainloop?
Because when i run 2 mainloop,the problem happend...

here is some code:

```
def enableChat(roomId,username):
    app1 = wx.PySimpleApp(None)
    frame_1 = MainGUI(None,roomId,username,"Chat")
    print "$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$",wx.GetTopLevelWindows()
    app1.MainLoop()

def enableChooseRoom(rooms,roomsOfUser):
    app2 = wx.PySimpleApp(None)
    frame_2 = ChooseRoomWindow(None,rooms,roomsOfUser,title="Choosing Room")
    print wx.GetTopLevelWindows()
    app2.MainLoop()
    return choice

t3 = threading.Thread(target=enableChat,args=(1,"ido",))
t3.start()
t4 = threading.Thread(target=enableChooseRoom,args=("1-sport 1-sport 2-movie","",))
t4.start()
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run two main loops at the same time. If the user goes into a different room, you should just open a new frame, tab, etc in the same application. You can many other frames from your main application or you could use a Notebook widget and follow Pidgin's design of opening new rooms / chat sessions in new tabs.

Also `wx.PySimpleApp` is deprecated. You should use `wx.App(False)` instead.

Comment: so where i run the second frame? in the 'ChooseRoomWindow' frame?  and run him in theard or simply just like function?

Comment: edit:i call to 'MainGui' from 'ChooseRoomWindow' like that:'MainGUI(None,roomId,username,"Chat")'.the program tell me - 'PyNoAppError:the wx.App object must be created first!'.what i need to do?

Comment: Whatever button or menu you use to open a new room, you can create the frame instance in its event handler and show it. The following tutorial shows how to do it: http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/06/27/wxpython-and-pubsub-a-simple-tutorial/. See its `hideFrame` method. You probably don't need the pubsub part.

Comment: now thw main gui stuck... i done what in the link(enable on frame and after choose room i hide him,then open the chat gui-stuck)what to do now? i run just 1 app with 2 frame one after one(the first hide while the second run)...\